# Node.js API to spawn off a call to another API

Tags: javascript, node.js, api

I created a Node.js API.
When this API gets called I return to the caller fairly quickly.  Which is good.

But now I also want API to call or launch an different API or function or something that will go off and run on it's own. Kind of like calling a child process with `child.unref()`.  In fact, I would use `child.spawn()` but I don't see how to have spawn() call another API.  **Maybe that alone would be my answer?**

Of this other process, I don't care if it crashes or finishes without error. 
 So it doesn't need to be attached to anything.  But if it does remain attached to the Node.js console then icing on the cake.

I'm still thinking about how to identify & what to do if the spawn somehow gets caught up in running a really long time.  But ready to cross that part of this yet.

**Your thoughts on what I might be able to do?**

Comment: var fork = require('child_process').fork;
var child = fork('./script'); where script will call another API

Comment: Great thought but the child can't fork because `Error: listen EADDRINUSE` it wants to have the same IP address & port the parent already is using.

Comment: script should contain code to make request to api not creating a new api server as port number is hardcoded thus you are getting that error.

Comment: First the process has to fork.  Forking copies the current process running in memory and lets the copy run on its own.  Then the forked process can read/execute the script.  Forking causes the error before there is even a chance for the process to read the script.  Unless you can provide an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess I could `child.spawn('node', [somescript])`
What do you think?
I would have to explore if my cloud host will permit this too.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify exactly what the other spawned thing is supposed to do.  If it is calling an HTTP API, with Node.js you should not launch a new process to do that.  Node is built to run HTTP requests asynchronously.

The normal pattern, if you really need some stuff to happen in a different process, is to use something like a message queue, the cluster module, or other messaging/queue between processes that the worker will monitor, and the worker is usually set up to handle some particular task or set of tasks this way.  It is pretty unusual to be spawning another process after receiving an HTTP request since launching new processes is pretty heavy-weight and can use up all of your server resources if you aren't careful, and due to Node's async capabilities usually isn't necessary especially for things mainly involving IO.

Answer (score 0):

This is from a test API I built some time ago. Note I'm even passing a value into the script as a parameter.

```
router.put('/test', function (req, res, next) {
    var u = req.body.u;
    var cp = require('child_process');
    var c = cp.spawn('node', ['yourtest.js',  '"' + u + '"'], { detach: true });
    c.unref();
    res.sendStatus(200);

});
```

The `yourtest.js` script can be just about anything you want it to be.  But I thought I would have enjoy learning more if I thought to first treat the script as a node.js console desktop app.  ***FIRST*** get your `yourtest.js` script to run without error by manually running/testing it from your console's command line `node yourstest.js yourparamtervalue`  ***THEN*** integrate it in to the `child.spawn()`

---

```
var u = process.argv[2];
console.log('f2u', u);

function f1() {
    console.log('f1-hello');
}

function f2() {
    console.log('f2-hello');
}
setTimeout(f2, 3000); // wait 3 second before execution f2().  I do this just for troubleshooting.  You can watch node.exe open and then close in TaskManager if node.exe is running long enough.

f1();
```